# Unable to establish connection, All host(s) tried for query failed

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax, cassandra-3.0

i know this may be basic problem but as i am new to cassandra and did not find solution of it anywhere so When i am trying to make connection in DataStax Dev Center to cassandra server, it is giving me below exception.

[image]

Below is system configuration:

Operating System: Windows 10 pro(64- Bit)

apache-cassandra-3.11.2

Below is cassandra.yaml configuration:

```
start_native_transport: true

broadcast_rpc_address: 1.2.3.4

native_transport_port_ssl: 9142

listen_address: 192.168.2.22

rpc_address: 192.x.x.x
```

I have done these changes in cassandra.yaml file: `start_rpc: true rpc_port: 9042`

when running this command on cmd: `nodetool -h localhost -p 9042 status`

getting this error: `Failed to connect to 'localhost:9042' - ConnectIOException: 'non-JRMP server at remote endpoint'.`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answer of this question and below are configurations which need to configure once you install Cassandra for first time:

```
broadcast_rpc_address: 192.168.2.22(ip address of system on which Cassandra is installed

rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have configured native-transport-port as :9142, but you are trying to connect to 9042 port with dev center. Please correct it and verify.

Comment: but my native_transport_port is 9042

Answer (score 1):

You have set rpc (rpc_port) to use the the same port as cql (native_transport_port). Are you sure you want to use rpc? This is the old deprecated interface and should not be used unless you need it for backwards compatibility.

If you actually do want to use rpc then it has to be another port than native_transport_port.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jmx port (7199 default) for nodetool